# How to handle alternative themes for visual impaired users

Tags: sharepoint, accessibility

Has anyone got an thoughts on how to handle theming a WSS site for a single user who is visually impaired ... she uses high contrast settings for Word, etc.

But still leave the usual theme for everyone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That second link on choppen's answer is one of the craziest/most clever workarounds I've ever seen haha.

By all means if you don't have much programming knowledge, use that idea.

Onto coding, you have different ways to achieve that, but without going into features and overriding sharepoint's render engine / site definitions, HttpModules and MasterPages sound more reasonable for this, MasterPages are even easier.

Have your code hooked in the Page_Load of the MasterPage and check if the SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName is your user and then append to the head object a secondary theme link:

```
<link href="/highcontrast.css" etc />
```

Remember if you put .NET code in the MasterPage you need to allow it on the web.config with the [PageParsePaths](http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2006/07/27/SharePoint-2007_3A00_-using-ASP.NET-server-side-code-in-your-pages.aspx). With a HttpModule override the Page_PreInit event in the Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

These posts may give you some ideas:

- http://sharepointmakesmecry.blogspot.com/2009/01/sharepoint-audience-targeted-branding.html
- http://sharepointmakesmecry.blogspot.com/2009/02/user-centric-themes-sharepoint-branding.html

Answer (score 1):

If the layout is done through css create a custom stylesheet for her and configure her browser to use that sheet for the specific sharepoint site. The following link may help.
http://www.microsoft.com/enable/training/ie6/formatpage.aspx